# Audio HTML5 Tag not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio

I'm in the middle of migrating my current website into Wordpress and was having troubles getting the audio HTML5 tag to work properly.  I am basically using a copy and pasted version of the existing code I've been using on the current website (see below, also note I have only edited the source src location to use the entire URL, replaced the php echo, and wrapped the audio tag within a div).

I have also already checked the files to see if they are valid.

Wordpress code:

```
    <div><audio controls="controls" preload="none" onPlay="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'Radio-2011-08-01']);">

        <source src="http://www.thelovelydaze.com/files/music/TLZRADIO08012011.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />        
        <source src="http://www.thelovelydaze.com/files/music/TLZRADIO08012011.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />

        Your browser does not support audio streaming.

</audio></div>
```

Current Code:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="none" onPlay="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'Radio-2011-08-01']);">

        <source src="../files/music/TLZRADIO08012011.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />        
        <source src="../files/music/TLZRADIO08012011.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />

        <?php echo $AudioNote ?>

</audio>
```

For reference:
Wordpress site: http://thelovelydaze.com/WP/2011/08/01/the-lovely-daze-radio-2/
Current site: http://www.thelovelydaze.com/music/tlz-radio-20110801.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the html5 js in your site. please add that as still all browsers ar not supporting html 5 and css 3

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

The website currently does not use any JS at all.  I do understand that all browsers do not support the HTML 5 audio tag as well, which is not a concern as most of our viewership are younger and do tend to have newer/up to date browsers and we upload both ogg and mp3 files for cross browser support.

Do you have any idea as to why it works on the current site, but not when I migrate it over to the Wordpress it fails to play?  Since it does work on the current site I figure it has to be a Wordpress issue, unless there is something wrong with the code I tweaked.